# Can't See "Please do not use these words in titles" without Scrolling

Tags: feature-request, questions, edits, title

When editing titles (to take out tags, for instance), I occasionally press Enter while the selection is in the "Title" text box, and nothing happens. After a while, I figure it out:

[image: Please Don't Do That]

The problem is that this is off-screen at the bottom, and I don't know it's there!

Please either display the box near the cursor at the time that Enter is pressed, or at least indicate that there is a validation error and that I should scroll down to see it. Maybe put a red border around the title box, with a red asterisk next to it, with a tooltip that says, "see below".

Comment: It looks like you're using a larger font size than normal. Could that be the problem?

Comment: There are no problems, only temporary impediments ©

Comment: I do have the screen set for a non-optimal size (1280x1024). The "optimal" size would be 1920x1200. This is my laptop, and I have the size set to match my desktop, since I remote desktop to it over a VPN. I had been wondering why I had tiny text, and the resolution was the answer.